# How to validate Date of Birth in javascript with input[type="Date"]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there are a few questions out there on this topic, but they all are either unclear or, they are using `input[type="text"]` in them.

In my HTML form I have an input of type date. So now I want to make sure that the date of birth is valid(Date is not in the future!). How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  [You are expected to have made an attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Make a Date instance from it and compare that to `new Date()`. `>` and `<` comparisons work the way you'd expect for dates.

Comment: So what is different with reading input text value and a date input value?

Comment: There are many great libraries out there for working with dates, for example, https://momentjs.com/ - have you tried using something like this.

Comment: Consider using the [`min` and `max` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Additional_attributes).

Comment: There's a whole section on [validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Validation) in MDN's documentation of `input type="date"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments have suggested a number of approaches, but for the specific functionality you're implementing, most of them are overkill. This only requires a simple comparison operation.

```js
document.getElementById("check").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  // Create a date variable which stores the current day at 00:00 local time.
  let today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  // Parse the provided date in the default YYYY-MM-DD format.
  let birthdate = new Date(document.getElementById("birthdate").value);

  // Check whether the provided date is equal to or less than the current date.
  if (birthdate <= today) {
   document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].textContent = "Valid!";
  } else {
   document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].textContent = "Invalid!";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="birthdate"/>
<button id="check">Check</button>
<span></span>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code request site. Answering questions that do not follow the community guidelines promotes more questions like this in the future.